# Converting any base64 file to a file and moving to the targeted path in php / Symfony 4

Tags: php, symfony, php-7, symfony4

thanks in advance I am creating the API in `symfony 4` for just uploading the `base64 image` or any file through `POSTMAN` and I have to move the file to the targeted directory. I have written the below code in the controller. Through controller I am trying to move the file to the directory, but

I am getting the error as :

> Uncaught Warning: file_put_contents(images/5c78de505abdd.svg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): Warning: file_put_contents(images/5c78de505abdd.svg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory at /home/ragiththomas/Sites/asco-forum/src/Modules/Forum/ForumController.php:1107)"} []

POSTMAN request for svg file:

```
{"postFile":"data:image/svg+xml;base64,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"}
```

CONTROLLER FILE:

```
/**
* @route("/uploadForumFiles", name="upload_forum_files", methods="POST")
*
* @access public
*
* @return JsonResponse
*/
public function uploadForumFiles(Request $request, PostsInterceptor $apiInterceptor, ContainerInterface $container): JsonResponse {
try {
$fileContent = $requestDtoObj->postFile;
$target_dir = 'images/'; // add the specific path to save the file
$decoded_file = base64_decode($fileContent); // decode the file
$mime_type = finfo_buffer(finfo_open(), $decoded_file, FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE); // extract mime type
$extension = $this->mime2ext($mime_type); // extract extension from mime type
$file = uniqid() .'.'. $extension; // rename file as a unique name
$file_dir = $target_dir. uniqid().'.'.$extension;
file_put_contents($target_dir, $file);
echo $file_dir; die;
} catch (Exception $ex) {

        $this->logger->writeLog("ERROR", "Exception while uploading a file " . $ex->getMessage() . 'at line - ' . $ex->getLine() . ' in file' . $ex->getFile());
        return $this->responseHandler->getFailedResponse(array($ex->getMessage()), $apiInterceptor);
    }
}




public function mime2ext($mime){
$all_mimes = '{"png":["image/png","image/x-png"],"bmp":["image/bmp","image/x-bmp",
"image/x-bitmap","image/x-xbitmap","image/x-win-bitmap","image/x-windows-bmp",
"image/ms-bmp","image/x-ms-bmp","application/bmp","application/x-bmp",
"application/x-win-bitmap"],"gif":["image/gif"],"jpeg":["image/jpeg",
"image/pjpeg"],"xspf":["application/xspf+xml"],"vlc":["application/videolan"],
"wmv":["video/x-ms-wmv","video/x-ms-asf"],"au":["audio/x-au"],
"ac3":["audio/ac3"],"flac":["audio/x-flac"],"ogg":["audio/ogg",
"video/ogg","application/ogg"],"kmz":["application/vnd.google-earth.kmz"],
"kml":["application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml"],"rtx":["text/richtext"],
"rtf":["text/rtf"],"jar":["application/java-archive","application/x-java-application",
"application/x-jar"],"zip":["application/x-zip","application/zip",
"application/x-zip-compressed","application/s-compressed","multipart/x-zip"],
"7zip":["application/x-compressed"],"xml":["application/xml","text/xml"],
"svg":["image/svg+xml","application/octet-stream"],"3g2":["video/3gpp2"],"3gp":["video/3gp","video/3gpp"],
"mp4":["video/mp4"],"m4a":["audio/x-m4a"],"f4v":["video/x-f4v"],"flv":["video/x-flv"],
"webm":["video/webm"],"aac":["audio/x-acc"],"m4u":["application/vnd.mpegurl"],
"pdf":["application/pdf"],
"pptx":["application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation"],
"ppt":["application/powerpoint","application/vnd.ms-powerpoint","application/vnd.ms-office",
"application/msword"],"docx":["application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"],
"xlsx":["application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet","application/vnd.ms-excel"],
"xl":["application/excel"],"xls":["application/msexcel","application/x-msexcel","application/x-ms-excel",
"application/x-excel","application/x-dos_ms_excel","application/xls","application/x-xls"],
"xsl":["text/xsl"],"mpeg":["video/mpeg"],"mov":["video/quicktime"],"avi":["video/x-msvideo",
"video/msvideo","video/avi","application/x-troff-msvideo"],"movie":["video/x-sgi-movie"],
"log":["text/x-log"],"txt":["text/plain"],"css":["text/css"],"html":["text/html"],
"wav":["audio/x-wav","audio/wave","audio/wav"],"xhtml":["application/xhtml+xml"],
"tar":["application/x-tar"],"tgz":["application/x-gzip-compressed"],"psd":["application/x-photoshop",
"image/vnd.adobe.photoshop"],"exe":["application/x-msdownload"],"js":["application/x-javascript"],
"mp3":["audio/mpeg","audio/mpg","audio/mpeg3","audio/mp3"],"rar":["application/x-rar","application/rar",
"application/x-rar-compressed"],"gzip":["application/x-gzip"],"hqx":["application/mac-binhex40",
"application/mac-binhex","application/x-binhex40","application/x-mac-binhex40"],
"cpt":["application/mac-compactpro"],"bin":["application/macbinary","application/mac-binary",
"application/x-binary","application/x-macbinary"],"oda":["application/oda"],
"ai":["application/postscript"],"smil":["application/smil"],"mif":["application/vnd.mif"],
"wbxml":["application/wbxml"],"wmlc":["application/wmlc"],"dcr":["application/x-director"],
"dvi":["application/x-dvi"],"gtar":["application/x-gtar"],"php":["application/x-httpd-php",
"application/php","application/x-php","text/php","text/x-php","application/x-httpd-php-source"],
"swf":["application/x-shockwave-flash"],"sit":["application/x-stuffit"],"z":["application/x-compress"],
"mid":["audio/midi"],"aif":["audio/x-aiff","audio/aiff"],"ram":["audio/x-pn-realaudio"],
"rpm":["audio/x-pn-realaudio-plugin"],"ra":["audio/x-realaudio"],"rv":["video/vnd.rn-realvideo"],
"jp2":["image/jp2","video/mj2","image/jpx","image/jpm"],"tiff":["image/tiff"],
"eml":["message/rfc822"],"pem":["application/x-x509-user-cert","application/x-pem-file"],
"p10":["application/x-pkcs10","application/pkcs10"],"p12":["application/x-pkcs12"],
"p7a":["application/x-pkcs7-signature"],"p7c":["application/pkcs7-mime","application/x-pkcs7-mime"],"p7r":["application/x-pkcs7-certreqresp"],"p7s":["application/pkcs7-signature"],"crt":["application/x-x509-ca-cert","application/pkix-cert"],"crl":["application/pkix-crl","application/pkcs-crl"],"pgp":["application/pgp"],"gpg":["application/gpg-keys"],"rsa":["application/x-pkcs7"],"ics":["text/calendar"],"zsh":["text/x-scriptzsh"],"cdr":["application/cdr","application/coreldraw","application/x-cdr","application/x-coreldraw","image/cdr","image/x-cdr","zz-application/zz-winassoc-cdr"],"wma":["audio/x-ms-wma"],"vcf":["text/x-vcard"],"srt":["text/srt"],"vtt":["text/vtt"],"ico":["image/x-icon","image/x-ico","image/vnd.microsoft.icon"],"csv":["text/x-comma-separated-values","text/comma-separated-values","application/vnd.msexcel"],"json":["application/json","text/json"]}';

$all_mimes = json_decode($all_mimes,true);
foreach ($all_mimes as $key => $value) {
    if(array_search($mime,$value) !== false) return $key;
}
return false;

}
```

Comment: So the error `Warning: file_put_contents(images/5c78de505abdd.svg): failed to open stream: No such file` is some kind of a mystery? Just create the file before trying to put anything inside.

Comment: I am creating the file from here   $file = uniqid() .'.'. $extension; you can see inside my uploadForumFiles function

Comment: I read your question. Also it's a method, not a function. And no, you did not **create** any file. By creating a file I mean physically write it to the hard drive. This can be done using [touch](http://php.net/touch).

Comment: Symfony has a builtin FileSystem class, you could use that to create files/folder and write stuff to it.

Comment: @emix what are you talking about, file_put_contents is perfectly able of _creating_ the file itself, if it doesn’t already exists. What it doesn’t do, is automatically create directories contained in the path, if those don’t actually exist yet - and that seems to be the case here.

Comment: You are trying to create and write a file to a non-existing directory : `/home/ragiththomas/Sites/asco-forum/src/Modules/Forum/images/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`file_put_contents` creates the file if it doesn't exist, but it fails if you try to put the file in a directory that doesn't exist. So you should try the following:

- check if the `images` directory exists
- check the write permissions of the directory
- try with an absolute path, so in your case probably `$target_dir = '/home/ragiththomas/Sites/asco-forum/images/';`

Comment: You should use `__DIR__` instead hardcoding the path

Comment: @Alexis you are totally right, hardcoding the path is never a good idea, but in this case it was only supposed to find the reason of the problem. In Symfony you can also use `kernel.project_dir` or `getProjectDir()`.

Comment: Thank you Alexis and Pawel Napierala , after using _DIR_ it's working fine

Answer (score 0):

With symfony4, another way is to use vichuploadbundle. We can take an example with image.

- according to this documentation [integrating vichuploadbundle](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/integration/vichuploaderbundle.html) , install vichupload and configure it

```
composer require vich/uploader-bundle
```

In the config/bundles.php file don't forget to check if this line appear :

```
Vich\UploaderBundle\VichUploaderBundle::class => ['all' => true],
```

In the config/services.yaml, add this configuration (it's just an example)

```
# config/services.yaml
parameters:
    app.path.images: /uploads/images
```

don't forget to create uploads directory inside public directory and images directory inside uploads directory.

And you configure the file config/packages/vich_uploader.yaml like :

```
# config/packages/vich_uploader.yaml
vich_uploader:
    db_driver: orm

    mappings:
        object_image:
            uri_prefix: '%app.path.images%'
            upload_destination:   '%kernel.project_dir%/public%app.path.images%'
            namer: Vich\UploaderBundle\Naming\UniqidNamer
            delete_on_remove: true
            delete_on_update: true
```

- create an image entity (with validation assert) like :

```
    <?php

    namespace App\Entity;

    use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;
    use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
    use Vich\UploaderBundle\Mapping\Annotation as Vich;

    /**
     * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\ImageRepository")
     * @Vich\Uploadable()
     * @ORM\Table(name="image")
     */
    class Image
    {
        /**
         * @ORM\Id()
         * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
         * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
         */
        private $id;

        /**
         * @var File|null
         * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Please upload a file.")
         * @Assert\File(
         *     maxSize = "1M",
         *     maxSizeMessage = "Maximum size allowed : {{ limit }} {{ suffix }}.",
         *     mimeTypes = {"image/png", "image/jpg", "image/jpeg"},
         *     mimeTypesMessage = "Allowed formats : png, jpg, jpeg."
         * )
         * @Vich\UploadableField(mapping="object_image", fileNameProperty="imageName")
         */
        private $imageFile;

        /**
         * @var string|null
         *
         * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
         */
        private $imageName;

        /**
         * @var \DateTime
         * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
         *
         */
        private $createdAt;

        /**
         * @var \DateTime
         * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
         */
        private $updatedAt;

        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->createdAt = new \DateTime('now');
        }

        public function getId(): ?int
        {
            return $this->id;
        }

        /**
         * @return \DateTime
         */
        public function getCreatedAt(): \DateTime
        {
            return $this->createdAt;
        }

        /**
         * @param \DateTime $createdAt
         * @return Image
         */
        public function setCreatedAt(\DateTime $createdAt)
        {
            $this->createdAt = $createdAt;
            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * @return \DateTime
         */
        public function getUpdatedAt(): \DateTime
        {
            return $this->updatedAt;
        }

        /**
         * @param \DateTime $updatedAt
         * @return Image
         */
        public function setUpdatedAt(\DateTime $updatedAt)
        {
            $this->updatedAt = $updatedAt;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * @return null|File
         */
        public function getImageFile(): ?File
        {
            return $this->imageFile;
        }

        /**
         * @param null|File $imageFile
         * @return Image
         */
        public function setImageFile(?File $imageFile): Image
        {
            $this->imageFile = $imageFile;

            if($this->imageFile instanceof UploadedFile) {
                $this->updatedAt = new \DateTime('now');
            }

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * @return null|string
         */
        public function getImageName(): ?string
        {
            return $this->imageName;
        }

        /**
         * @param null|string $imageName
         * @return Image
         */
        public function setImageName(?string $imageName): Image
        {
            $this->imageName = $imageName;
            return $this;
        }

    }
```

create a form image entity like :

```
    <?php

    namespace App\Form;

    use App\Entity\Image;
    use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
    use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\FileType;
    use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
    use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

    class ImageType extends AbstractType
    {
        public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
        {
            $builder
                ->add('imageFile', FileType::class)
            ;
        }

        public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
        {
            $resolver->setDefaults([
                'data_class' => Image::class
            ]);
        }
    }
```

- you create an UploadedBase64File service (in Utils directory that you will create ) like

```
    <?php

    namespace App\Utils;

    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;

    class UploadedBase64File extends UploadedFile
    {

        public function __construct(string $base64Content, string $originalName)
        {
            $filePath = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'UploadedFile');
            $data = base64_decode($this->getBase64String($base64Content));
            file_put_contents($filePath, $data);
            $error = null;
            $mimeType = null;
            $test = true;

            parent::__construct($filePath, $originalName, $mimeType, $error, $test);
        }

        private function getBase64String(string $base64Content)
        {

            $data = explode(';base64,', $base64Content);
            return $data[1];

        }

    }
```

- Finally in a controller, you can do something like :

```
    <?php

    namespace App\Controller\Api;

    use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
    use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
    use App\Utils\UploadedBase64File;

    class CoreController extends AbstractController
    {
       /**
         * @Route("/api/images", methods={"POST"}, name="api_add_image")
         */
         public function addImage(Request $request) 
         {
             $data = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);
             if($data === null
                || !is_array($data)
                || count($data) !== 1
                || !isset($data['image']['name'], $data['image']['value'])
                || count($data['image']) !== 2
             ) {
                // Throw invalid format request for image
             }

             $imageFile = new UploadedBase64File($data['image']['value'], $data['image']['name']);
             $image = new Image();
             $form = $this->createForm(ImageType::class, $image, ['csrf_protection' => false]);
             $form->submit(['imageFile' => $imageFile]);  

             if(!($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid())) {
                 // Send json form error
             }

             // Persist, do thing you want to do and send json response 
         }
   }
```

And if you want to test in postman, you  can do something like :

```
    {
        "image": {
            "name": "originalfilename.png",
            "value": "base64 content"
        }
    }
```

This is an attempt of other solution.

Comment: Nice solution, we thank you for this. I for example I`m unable to use it, apparently it fails to get the file extension and then tries to safe the file without it... which fails.

Comment: @Mecanik, which base64 string do you upload : the one with extension or the one without extension ?