# API Platform / React - uploading file not working

Tags: reactjs, symfony, file-upload, multipartform-data, api-platform.com

I'm trying to send an image to my **API** with React using a **formData** and **Axios** but my request in my custom controller shows null. **When I use PostMan my api accepts the image fine.**

In the headers of my axios request I have to add a boundary when without, it tells me a "**missing boundary**" error, however in the doc I can't find any info about that...

This is my request with **Axios**

```
const bodyFormData  = new FormData()
bodyFormData.append('name',info.name)
bodyFormData.append('description',info.description)
bodyFormData.append('price',info.price)
bodyFormData.append('file', info.image,"image.jpg")

await Axios({
    method: "post",
    url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/products/upload",
    data: bodyFormData,
    headers: {  'Content-Type': `multipart/form-data; boundary=${bodyFormData._boundary}` },
    
    }).then(response=>console.log(response.data));
```

and my **custom controller** (works with **PostMan**)

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\Product;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\Exception\FileException;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\BadRequestHttpException;

class UploadProductController extends AbstractController
{

    private $manager;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $manager){
        $this->manager = $manager;
    }

   public function __invoke(Request $request)
   {
        $uploadedFile = $request->files->get('file');
        if (!$uploadedFile) {
            throw new BadRequestHttpException('"file" is required');
        }

        dd($uploadedFile);
   }
}
```

the answer is always "file is required" with React **but with PostMan I have a file...**

Comment: Did you try [checking if the file is available as a base64 encoded string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61930587/8381334)?

Answer (score 0):

Two possible solutions:

1. Try to send with XMLHttpRequest. Add the header `'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'`. It works for me with Axios but on a standalone Symfony project (without API-Platform). I'm not sure if it can work in your case, but you can try.
2. Another solution is to remove headers. I had the same problem on a API-Platform project with VueJS and Fetch API in front. I don't remember where I see that, it seems API-Platform has a problem with the multipart/form-data. Your request will look like:

```
  await Axios({
      method: "post",
      url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/products/upload",
      data: bodyFormData,
  }).then(response=>console.log(response.data));
```

It's weird, but it's what I'm doing, and it works fine. Sorry for the lack of explanation.